# compile passenger 5.2 on freebsd 10.3 with nginx 1.12.2

Tags: nginx, passenger, freebsd

I do install passenger with gem install and get the version 5.2.
Then I go to the gem directory and run `rake nginx:as_dynamic_module`

The result is

```
In file included from src/agent/Core/ApplicationPool/Implementation.cpp:39:
src/cxx_supportlib/Hooks.h:146:31: error: use of undeclared identifier
      'WEXITSTATUS'
                        ") exited with status " << WEXITSTATUS(info.status));
                                                   ^
src/cxx_supportlib/LoggingKit/Logging.h:95:51: note: expanded from macro
      'P_INFO'
        Passenger::LoggingKit::INFO, __FILE__, __LINE__, expr)
                                                         ^
src/cxx_supportlib/LoggingKit/Logging.h:48:16: note: expanded from macro 'P_LOG'
                        _ostream << expr << "\n"; \
                                    ^
1 error generated.
rake aborted!
```

passenger Version 5.1.12 was and is still compilable and is working.

How can I fix the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `passenger` cannot be compiled with `clang`? Anyway, it's also installable from ports: https://www.freshports.org/www/rubygem-passenger/ and as a package in `nginx` and `apache` flavors:

```
pkg install rubygem-passenger-nginx
```

Comment: i'll try. but this is not version 5.2

Comment: I've tried but there is no dynamic module for nginx? do you know what's the lines to integrate into nginx config?